# Files deleted from network share. Where would they go?

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-recovery

I've had a question posed to me by a user, they've deleted some files from a network share, and they're looking at somehow recovering them.

Of course, if they go for file recovery, it will have to take place on the computer that held the file, however if under normal circumstances, on a local computer, when deleting files go to the recycle bin. But what happens to files when you delete them on a remote computer's share? Do they get copied to the local users Recycle Bin, or sent to the server's Recycle Bin?

This is just a standard Windows share, on a work-group, accessed as `\\computernam\shared-folder-name`.

The 'server' is Windows XP, and the client's probably XP.

Comment: as psycogeek said its gone and the only way to get it back would be third party software if any exists.

Comment: Thanks alot, I had kind of figured they'd probably be gone, but I've never been asked the question :)

Answer (score 1):

they are deleted.  not recycled. but they are not gone from the disk till overwritten. You already know about recovering.

if you had various protections running, you could also recover from there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy